# Excluir valores de una lista python

Tags: python

Estoy buscando realizar algo semejante a esto, para cada `item` del array `url` menos el `item` de indice 0:

```
url = ['a.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for item in url[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]:
    data ={
        "adSize": {"id":'{}'.format(item) }
        }
```

pero de este modo tengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: ˋfor item in url[1:]:ˋ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` es una sintaxis incorrecta, tal como muestra el error el indice de una lista  tiene que ser un entero. `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7` es solo azúcar sintáctica para crear una tupla, es decir lo anterior equivale a `url[(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)]`.

Si quieres iterar sobre todos los elemento de una lista menos el primero tienes varias opciones:

- Rebanado(Slicing):

  ```
  url = ['a.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  for item in url[1:]:
      print(item)
  ```

  Simple y buena opción para listas con pocos elementos, pero crea una copia del objeto lo cual no es muy eficiente para listas con muchos elementos.
- Usar un iterador y consumir el primer elemento antes del `for`. Posiblemente la mejor opción para listas relativamente extensas:

  ```
  url = ['a.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

  url_iter = iter(url)
  next(url_iter)

  for item in url_iter:
      print(item)
  ```
- Usar [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

  ```
  from itertools import islice


  url = ['a.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  for item in islice(url, 1, None):
      print(item)
  ```

Comment: Gracias animal! Abrazo

Answer (score 0):

Para excluir el primer elemento puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
url = ['a.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for item in url[1:]:
    data ={
        "adSize": {"id":'{}'.format(item) }
        }
```

Se obtendrán todos los valores a excepción del primero ('a.com').

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -negativo, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.